# What am I doing wrong in this where statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using the following logic in my where statement.

If I do just the statement below then it returns results

```
where a.CONDITION_NAME like '%colon%' and a.STUDY_CRITERIA like '%braf%'
```

However if I expand on the where logic to the following statement it returns no results. Why? Shouldn't it return the same thing as where statement above?

```
where a.CONDITION_NAME like '%colon%' and a.STUDY_CRITERIA like '%braf%' and
(a.SHORT_TITLE like '%braf%' or 
 a.STUDY_TITLE like '%braf%' or
 a.DESCRIPTION like '%braf%')
```

Basically what I want is the following. I need it to find records where the condition name is like colon and the study criteria field is like braf. But since there are other fields that can contain the braf term, I need it to search whether short title or study title or description contain the braf term as well. Is there a different way to code that up? This is done in pgadmin4 via postgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your explanation it should be

```
where a.CONDITION_NAME like '%colon%' and 
    (a.STUDY_CRITERIA like '%braf%' or
     a.SHORT_TITLE like '%braf%' or 
     a.STUDY_TITLE like '%braf%' or
     a.DESCRIPTION like '%braf%')
```

Comment: Thank you this works well and I believe it gives me what I need : )

Answer (score 0):

This is because your adding `AND` condition on your `OR` group.

so it will result to `1 && 0` which is `0`.

```
where (a.CONDITION_NAME like '%colon%' and a.STUDY_CRITERIA like '%braf%') or
(a.SHORT_TITLE like '%braf%' or 
 a.STUDY_TITLE like '%braf%' or
 a.DESCRIPTION like '%braf%')
```

Change this to `OR` condition.

Comment: The original condition is correct. Condition_Name and Study_Ctiteria must be as indicated AND at least 1 of the other 3 must be as indicated. What does the query: Select * from .... where a.SHORT_TITLE like '%braf%' or 
 a.STUDY_TITLE like '%braf%' or
 a.DESCRIPTION like '%braf%';"     That will be "No rows returned". It is **NOT** a query issue; it is a **DATA** issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because the following part returns false :

```
(a.SHORT_TITLE like '%braf%' or 
 a.STUDY_TITLE like '%braf%' or
 a.DESCRIPTION like '%braf%')
```

Remember that in logic

> 1 AND 0 returns 0, 1 OR 0 returns 1.

. I do not know what you exactly need, but you can change the last AND to OR if it works as you need.